# Twenty Thirteen get_sidebar Question

Tags: sidebar

I've been looking at Twenty Thirteen's code structure and thought I could learn a thing or two about theme development.

There's something that I haven't found an answer to:

Twenty Thirteen's widget areas are called by just using `get_sidebar()`. However, there are 2 sidebar files in the theme's folder - sidebar-main.php, sidebar.php.

From what I understand, sidebar-main.php can be called by defining the parameter of `get_sidebar('main')`. In Twenty Thirteen's case, I see no code which calls that, yet `is_active_sidebar('sidebar-1')` is executed.

**How does it call sidebar-main.php without defining the parameter?**

Another thing I've tried doing is switching the file names. The one with 'sidebar-2' to sidebar-main.php and 'sidebar-1' to sidebar.php. Everything screws up! The right sidebar widget isn't in place and the footer widget doesn't even show.

[image]

**How is Twenty Thirteen calling it's sidebars?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into `footer.php`?

Comment: Omg! I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of all the `get_sidebar()` calls from the TwentyThirteen files:

- `taxonomy-post_format.php:  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `search.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `single.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `archive.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `index.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `page.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `tag.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `category.php:<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`
- `author.php: <?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

and

- `footer.php: <?php get_sidebar( 'main' ); ?>`

Hope this helps ...

Comment: I think I need to stop and get some rest now. Sorry for this redundant question.

Comment: No problem, it happens to me all the time ...  ;-)